# Oracle session and process reaching max utilization issue with Oracle 18c+Tomcat9

Tags: tomcat9, oracle18c

Currently we migrated to Oracle 18c+Tomcat 9 after which we are experiencing max utilization issue both process and session.

```
 INST_ID RESOURCE_NAME        CURRENT_UTILIZATION MAX_UTILIZATION LIMIT_VALUE
 -------- -------------------- ------------------- --------------- ------------
     1    processes                      925            1000       1000
     1    sessions                       945            1020       1522
```

On further querying most of the utilization are observed from DB,

```
   SELECT machine, count(*) FROM v$session GROUP BY machine ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
   
                 MACHINE     COUNT(*)
                 --------     ----------
                 1825(DB)       591
                 0058(APP)      332
```

Could you please assist me how to address this issue and find an permanent solution. As a temporary workaround i'm clearing all inactive sessions from DB using kill session.

Please find my server.xml configurations

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
   connectionTimeout="20000"
   acceptCount="500"
   maxSavePostSize="0"
   disableUploadTimeout="true"
   enableLookups="false"
   maxThreads="450"
   removeAbandonedTimeout="60" removeAbandoned="true"
    logAbandoned="true"
    SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"   />
```

Comment: HI.Can anyone help me how to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If your app needs that many connections then you can increase processes parameter.

Comment: Thanks Tom,But could you let me know what is causing this session and process keep increasing every hour?

Comment: Could anyone tel me any solution please